# Evil Twin attack: How to make client send WPA2-PSK password when asked for AP-password?

Tags: network, wpa2, wpa2-psk

> How can an Evil Twin attack be set up, so that the client will be prompted for a password and send it in plain text?

Is the above even possible? I have already set up the fake AP, but it must be configured correctly.

Which tool will be best suited for the job, and could someone provide details on how to execute the attack / find knowledge, if possible?

Comment: https://www.cybrary.it/0p3n/evil-twin-attack-using-kali-linux/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible without knowing the password (WPA prevents this). However, you can set up an open fake accesspoint and use a captive portal to get the password in clear text. This would require you to social engineer the target into connecting to your accesspoint. You can for example keep sending deauth requests to the real AP and let the captive portal on your fake AP be a fake update page.

Comment: Thank you - Nice to know. Could you point to a tutorial on how to set up the portal?